# Unaccountable spreading image in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am trying to write my first game in JavaScript and HTML5 but I am stuck. I want to only draw a image into HTML canvas which has set background-image but the image is still magnified and additionally bad positioned and I don't know why. Let's show my code.

In HTML file in body I have only canvas #gameCanvas, that's all.

And this is JavaSript code.

```
function prepare()
{
    var canvas = $('#gameCanvas');
    var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

    $('#wrapper').css({"width": "704"});

    canvas.css({"width": "704",
        "height": "672",
        "backgroundImage": "url(./images/map.png)"});

    var player1 = new Image();
    player1.src = "./images/player1.png";
    player1.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(player1, 0, 0, 26, 36, 100, 100, 26, 36);
    };
}

$(function(){
    prepare();
})
```

And that's my weird result -> [1.result](http://oi39.tinypic.com/2dtdqq1.jpg)

I find out that when I remove setting of css properties width and height of canvas it draws image correct but canvas has only default size of according to browser. -> [2.result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnV7N.jpg)

I am totally confused.

Comment: try moving `player1.src` below `player.onload`

Comment: yeah.. i didn't think so but i was googling and saw that's how other examples were. i didn't really think it would be the problem but for shits and grins i mentioned it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using CSS to set the size of the canvas. This will only enlarge the default 300x150 sized canvas to the size you set with CSS (like if it was an image) (and besides, for CSS to work with other values than 0 you need to specify a unit - but ignore this for a moment).

You need to set the size explicitly using the canvas properties (attributes) `width` and `height`.

```
canvas[0].width = 704;   // no unit required for the attributes
canvas[0].height = 672;
```